# Want my JButton to return a previous area of text

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

I am trying to create a GUI that gives you hints when the program is opened. I am not sure how I am going to be able to add my text and then create buttons that allow me to go to the next text or return to the previous. I am not sure what type of actionListener I should use for that.

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;


public class HelpfulHints extends JFrame{

    private JTextArea area; //This is my textarea to display hints
    private JPanel panel;
    private JButton close, previous, next; //Three buttons to operate program

    public HelpfulHints(){

        super("Tip of the Day");
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER));

        //Create first button
        close= new JButton("Close");
        add(close);

        //Create second button
        previous = new JButton("Previous");
        add(previous);

        //Create third button
        next = new JButton("Next");
        add(next);

        //Add buttons to panel
        panel.add(close);
        panel.add(previous);
        panel.add(next);

        //Keep buttons to south of panel
        add(panel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        //Create ButtonHandler for button event handling
        ButtonHandler handler = new ButtonHandler();
        close.addActionListener(handler);
        previous.addActionListener(handler);
        next.addActionListener(handler);

        //Create the helpful hint area on the screen
        area = new JTextArea();
        area.setEditable(true);
        area.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER));

        add(area, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        setVisible(true);

    }

    //Inner class for button event handling
    private class ButtonHandler implements ActionListener{

        //handle Button event
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){


        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I am unclear about what exactly the buttons should do. Why would you use buttons to 'go' from text box to another text box? Isn't that what the tab key or the mouse is for?

Comment: [How to use tool tips](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/tooltip.html)?

Comment: @RudolphEst it is going to give u the option to either view a new tip or hint and/or go back to the previous one. I want only one tip to appear at start and dissapear if the next button is hit, and come back if the previous button is clicked

Comment: @TemptMyTerror are you trying to get tooltip for your button? Please specify.

Answer (score 1):

I have updated the content of listener for your needs.

```
private JTextArea area; //This is my textarea to display hints
private JPanel panel;
private JButton close, previous, next; //Three buttons to operate program
private List<String> tips = new ArrayList<String>();
private int displayedTipIndex = 0;

public HelpfulHints(){
    super("Tip of the Day");
    // set up your tips
    tips.add("First Tip");
    tips.add("Second Tip");
    tips.add("Third Tip");

    // ... your other code stays the same...

    //Create the helpful hint area on the screen
    area = new JTextArea();
    area.setEditable(true);
    area.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER));
    // set first tip
    area.setText(tips.get(displayedTipIndex));
    add(area, BorderLayout.CENTER);    

    // disable previous button when we start
    previous.setEnabled(false);

    //
    setVisible(true);        
}

//Inner class for button event handling
private class ButtonHandler implements ActionListener{

    //handle Button event
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
        if(e.getSource()==next){
            displayedTipIndex++;
            area.setText(tips.get(displayedTipIndex));
            // disable the next button if no more tips
            if(displayedTipIndex>=tips.size()-1){
                next.setEnabled(false);
            }
            // re-enable previpous button
            previous.setEnabled(true);
        }
        if(e.getSource()==previous){
            displayedTipIndex--;
            area.setText(tips.get(displayedTipIndex));
            /// disable the previous button if no more tips
            if(displayedTipIndex<0){
                previous.setEnabled(false);
            }
            // re-enable next button
            next.setEnabled(true);
        }
        if(e.getSource()==close){
            System.exit(0);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks a lot! helped me out quite a bit !! appreciate it